# PHP urlencode string and send back to main page?

Tags: php, url, urlencode

Can't figure out why my header() is not working. I have two pages

(1) all_people_page.php
(2) editmember.php

page (1) has a form that goes to page (2). Page (2) updates the database and needs to go back to page (1). BUT i want to trigger a notification on page(1) that tells the user the database has been updated. I figured if I urlencode a string then I can gather that variable to initiate a notification.

My problem is that I can't even go back to page (1) "all_people_page.php"

editmember.php:

```
<?php
  .... all my $_POST variables ....

  require ('db.php');
    $db = null;
    $limit = 10;
    $counter = 0;

    while (true) {
    try {
        $db = new PDO($dsn, $uname, $pword);
        $db->exec( "SET CHARACTER SET utf8" );
        $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
        $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, true );
        break;
    }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $db = null;
            $counter++;
            if ($counter == $limit)
                throw $e;
        }
    }

    try
        {       
     $result = $db->prepare("UPDATE member_db SET USER_SEX=?, FIRSTNAME=?, LASTNAME=?, SPOUSE_ATT=?, ADDRESS=?, CITY=?, STATE=?, ZIP=?, BDAY=?, LG_NUM=?, CAMPUS=? WHERE IDNUM=?");
     $result->execute(array($gender,$member_fname,$member_lname,$spouse_att_rad,$member_address,$member_city,$member_state,$member_zip,$bday,$lg_type,$campus,$member_id));

    $notify = 1;
    $url = "http://localhost/testsite/all_people_page.php?notify=". urlencode($notify);
    header(" Location: $url ");

    }
       catch ( PDOException $exception )
    {
       echo "PDO error :" . $exception->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: Your main question is about doing a redirect. You should leave out all database code and information, and re-post it as a different question if the database is also a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're using spaces in your header declaration.

Replace

```
header(" Location: $url ");
```

with

```
header("Location: $url");
```

Answer (score 1):

First be sure that line containing header is being executed, if it is ok then use

```
header('Location:'.$url);
```

instead of

```
header("Location:$url");
```

For displaying the notification on all_people_page.php, you can use session. Create a session indicating that database has been updated on editmember.php. When page redirect to all_people_page.php check the value of this session variable on all_people_page.php. If it is found correct than display message indicating that database has been updated.
At the end of the all_people_page.php unset this session variable.